# Extending a tidyverse function via `...`

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to extend my `foo` function below by allowing user to define any number of arguments in place of `...`.

These `...` arguments will exactly be treated as the current 3 arguments (`time`, `outcome`, `trt_gr`).

Is this possible in R?

```
foo <- function(time = 1, outcome = 1, trt_gr = 1, ...){

  time <- seq_len(time)
  outcome <- seq_len(outcome)
  trt_gr <- seq_len(trt_gr)
  
data <- expand.grid(time = time, outcome = outcome, trt_gr = trt_gr, info. = c("control","treatment"))

data %>% 
  group_by(outcome, time, trt_gr) %>%
  summarise(info. = str_c(sort(info., decreasing = TRUE), 
                          collapse = ' vs. '), .groups = 'drop') 
}

# EXAMPLE OF CURRENT USE:

foo()

#  outcome  time trt_gr info.                
#    <int> <int>  <int> <chr>                
#1       1     1      1 treatment vs. control
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible. We can replace your arguments with the elipsis `...` and allow the function to produce any amount of columns of with custom column names. Here is such a function in the tidyverse style:

```r
library(tidyverse)

foo <- function(...){
  
  dots <- rlang::list2(...) 
  var_nms <- names(dots)
  inp <- purrr::map(dots, seq_len)

  data <- tidyr::expand_grid(!!! inp,
                             info. = c("control","treatment"))
  
  data %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(!!!syms(var_nms)) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(info. = stringr::str_c(sort(info., decreasing = TRUE), 
                                            collapse = ' vs. '), .groups = 'drop') 
}

foo(time = 1, outcome = 1, trt_gr = 1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>    time outcome trt_gr info.                
#>   <int>   <int>  <int> <chr>                
#> 1     1       1      1 treatment vs. control

foo(some = 2, new = 1, colnames = 3)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>    some   new colnames info.                
#>   <int> <int>    <int> <chr>                
#> 1     1     1        1 treatment vs. control
#> 2     1     1        2 treatment vs. control
#> 3     1     1        3 treatment vs. control
#> 4     2     1        1 treatment vs. control
#> 5     2     1        2 treatment vs. control
#> 6     2     1        3 treatment vs. control
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Update**

To answer the added question in the comments. Yes we can vectorize the function above in the following way which also allows to skip columns in a run, when they contain a `0`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

foo <- function(...){
  
  dots <- rlang::list2(...) 
  var_nms <- names(dots)
  inp_ls <- map(dots, ~ map(.x, seq_len)) %>% transpose %>% map(compact)
  
  data_ls <- map(inp_ls, 
                 ~ tidyr::expand_grid(!!! .x,
                                      info. = c("control","treatment")))
  
  map2(data_ls, inp_ls, ~ .x %>% 
        dplyr::group_by(!!!syms(names(.y))) %>%
        dplyr::summarise(info. = stringr::str_c(sort(info., decreasing = TRUE), 
                                                collapse = ' vs. '), .groups = 'drop')) 
}

foo(some = c(1,2), new = c(1,0), colnames = c(1,3))
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>    some   new colnames info.                
#>   <int> <int>    <int> <chr>                
#> 1     1     1        1 treatment vs. control
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>    some colnames info.                
#>   <int>    <int> <chr>                
#> 1     1        1 treatment vs. control
#> 2     1        2 treatment vs. control
#> 3     1        3 treatment vs. control
#> 4     2        1 treatment vs. control
#> 5     2        2 treatment vs. control
#> 6     2        3 treatment vs. control
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @Reza: Yes this is possible too. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Reza: I think I would need to see an example of what you mean. With "round 1" you mean the first data.frame in the list? And "control" would not be another column but a special argument that we use to control something (I haven't understood that part yet).

Comment: @Reza: Now I understood. I updated the answer!

Comment: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69139305/16760971) is a question of interest.