# Vectorizing a tidyverse function with `...`

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, vectorization, rlang

Function `foo` below recodes the numeric column `var1` into a string column (`1 -->` `"a"`, `2 -->` `"b"` etc.).

I was wondering how to vectorize this function such that instead of argument `var1` we have argument `...`?

That is, all variables provided in `...` should undergo what `var1` undergoes in `foo`.

A possible useful post might be [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68945059/16762740).

```
library(tidyverse)

foo <- function(data, var1, caps = FALSE, reverse = FALSE){
  
let <-  if(caps) base::LETTERS else base::letters
FUN <- if(reverse) utils::tail else utils::head

data %>% mutate(var1 = factor(FUN(let, max(var1))[var1]))  
}

# EXAMPLE OF USE:
(dat <- data.frame(var1 = c(2,1,3,1,4:1), id = 1:8))

foo(dat, var1, caps = T, reverse = T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach below should do what you are looking for. It is not as clean as my answer to the linked post in your question, but it should work as expected (now also updated with default arguments that apply to all variables):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

foo <- function(data, ..., caps = FALSE, reverse = FALSE){
  
  var_ls <- map(ensyms(..., .named = TRUE), as.character)
  l_varls <- length(var_ls) 
  
  if(l_varls != length(caps)) {
    caps <- rep(caps, l_varls)
  }
  if(l_varls != length(reverse)) {
    reverse <- rep(reverse, l_varls)
  }
  
  let <- ifelse(caps, list(base::LETTERS), list(base::letters))
  names(let) <- names(var_ls)
  FUN <- ifelse(reverse, list(utils::tail), list(utils::head))
  names(FUN) <- names(var_ls)
  
  mutate(data,
         purrr::map_dfc(var_ls,
                        ~ factor(FUN[[.x]](let[[.x]],max(data[[.x]]))[data[[.x]]]))
         )
  
}

# EXAMPLE OF USE:
(dat <- data.frame(var1 = c(2,1,3,1,4:1), var2 = c(8:1), id = 1:8))
#>   var1 var2 id
#> 1    2    8  1
#> 2    1    7  2
#> 3    3    6  3
#> 4    1    5  4
#> 5    4    4  5
#> 6    3    3  6
#> 7    2    2  7
#> 8    1    1  8

foo(dat, var1, var2, caps = c(TRUE,FALSE), reverse = c(FALSE, TRUE))
#>   var1 var2 id
#> 1    B    z  1
#> 2    A    y  2
#> 3    C    x  3
#> 4    A    w  4
#> 5    D    v  5
#> 6    C    u  6
#> 7    B    t  7
#> 8    A    s  8
foo(dat, var1, var2)
#>   var1 var2 id
#> 1    b    h  1
#> 2    a    g  2
#> 3    c    f  3
#> 4    a    e  4
#> 5    d    d  5
#> 6    c    c  6
#> 7    b    b  7
#> 8    a    a  8
foo(dat, var1, var2, caps = TRUE, reverse = TRUE)
#>   var1 var2 id
#> 1    X    Z  1
#> 2    W    Y  2
#> 3    Y    X  3
#> 4    W    W  4
#> 5    Z    V  5
#> 6    Y    U  6
#> 7    X    T  7
#> 8    W    S  8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @SimonHarmel: I updated my answer which now includes default arguments which will automatically expand to all specified vars. Changing outputs according to the number of input columns requires some thinking and might be worth a new question.

Comment: Dear Tim, I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69834187/16762740) is also right up your alley.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `across` -

```
foo <- function(data, caps = FALSE, reverse = FALSE, ...){
  vars <- rlang::ensyms(...) 
  let <-  if(caps) base::LETTERS else base::letters
  FUN <- if(reverse) utils::tail else utils::head
  
  data %>% mutate(across(as.character(vars), ~factor(FUN(let, max(.))[.])))  
}

dat <- data.frame(var1 = c(2,1,3,1,4:1), id = 1:8)
foo(dat, caps = T, reverse = T, var1)

#  var1 id
#1    X  1
#2    W  2
#3    Y  3
#4    W  4
#5    Z  5
#6    Y  6
#7    X  7
#8    W  8

foo(dat, caps = T, reverse = T, var1, id)

#  var1 id
#1    X  S
#2    W  T
#3    Y  U
#4    W  V
#5    Z  W
#6    Y  X
#7    X  Y
#8    W  Z
```

Comment: I don't think that post is relevant here. There you are passing named values to the function not the column names. If you want to pass `...` without quotation try the updated answer.

Comment: Sure, but arguments `caps` and `reverse` are not vectorized, is there a way for `foo(dat, caps = c(T,F), reverse = c(F,T), var1, id)` to work?

Comment: You can use `...` inside `across(c(...), ~`.